# Grunt Libsass not showing error messages

Tags: sass, libsass

I've intstalled a grunt-libsass, only issue im having is it doesnt show error messageson the browser, so i have no idea wheres the broken code located, or anything. Its showing the errors on terminal but im not gonna open the terminal everytime.

Is theres a way to enable or show the error messages on the browser?

thanks